# How to display characters of any language on the screen using opengl

Tags: opengl

My requirement is to display string of any language on the screen.

Currently we are using opengl to display English characters.
Same APIs are not working for other languages. Instead of characters, boxes are displayed on screen.

Can someone help in understanding opengl and find appropriate APIs to display charterers of any language?

Answer (score 1):

> Currently we are using opengl to display English characters.

No, you're not using OpenGL. How do I know this? Because OpenGL does not do text rendering. All it does it points, lines and triangles.

What you're using is **some** library that knows how to draw characters with points, lines and triangles and then uses OpenGL to get that job done. And the particular library you're using apparently doesn't know, how to deal with characters outside of the ASCII character set.

Of course it's not just that what matters. *Encoding* matters as well. The most recent versions of C++ support *Unicode* in program sources (so that you can write unicode in string literals), but that does not automatically give you unicode support in your program – it's just the compiler who knows how to deal with it, but that knowledge does not automatically transpire into the compiled program.

So far there is only one operating system in which Unicode support is so deeply ingrained that no extra work is required; in fact a particular way of encoding Unicode was invented for it, but unfortunately this is one of the most niche OS projects there is around: Plan9

Apart from Unicode, there are also **many** other character encoding schemes, all incompatible with each other, each for a particular kind of writing. Which means, that it's also impossible to mix characters from different writing systems in texts encoding with such localized characters sets. Hence a **uni**versal en**cod**ing scheme was invented.

You're most likely on Windows, Linux, BSD, Solaris or MacOS X. And in all of them making non-ASCII-characters work means extra work for you, the programmer. MacOS X is probably the one OS with the least barrier of entry.

So here are the questions you have to answer for yourself:

- what character encoding used (hopefully Unicode)?
- does the text renderer library used support code points in that encoding?
- does the text renderer library come with a layout engine (the thing that positions characters) or does this have to be supplied extra?

Among the existing text renderers that can draw to OpenGL, currently Freetype-GL is the most capable; it has support for Unicode

https://github.com/rougier/freetype-gl